# How do I apply a style based on a condition (return value from a function in JS)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using simple html and associated JS code. I have a statement like this in my html code:

```
  <td class="ui-navigation-static-menu-holder" style="width: 147px; display: block">
```

I want to apply the `display: block` style only when a particular condition is true (say isStyleBlock() in my associated JS code).

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Could you please show us what you have done...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(isStyleBlock()) {
  elem.style.display = 'block'
}
```